# mySQL more precision using LIKE function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm aware of the `LIKE` function in SQL, but I need to do something slightly more complex.

In my table `people` I have a text field called `banned` which stores a string of all banned names seperated with a `@`. So let's `banned = Roger@Bobjob@Billy`

Say I want to check if the name `Bob` appears

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE banned LIKE '%$Bob%'
```

This would presumably find results because of the `Bobjob` in the string.

Is there any way I can make it so it only finds full names within the `@` delimiters?

Comment: Why are all your banned users stores in 1 string? Unless I'm missing something. That's just a bad structure

Comment: Its not actually for banned users, its for a feature on my site where only 2 or 3 names would ever be used, I just used banned for simpler explanation

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: maybe... `Where concat('@', banned,'@') like '%@Bob@%'`  but forgetaboutusing indexes.  or `find_in_set('Bob',replace(banned,','))>1`?

Comment: You can't have a non relational style entry in a relational database and expect the relational database to be able to deal with it effectively. That being said MySQL does allow regular expressions with `WHERE list REGEXP '...'`

Comment: You have 6 answers already on this question.  Don't make edits to your question that invalidate those answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about using index in either of these....  but since you're using %var% i am assuming you expected that already.

We could concat a @ at start and end of banned so that every name is surrounded by @'s then use the @ in the name search.  (Expects no name to have @ in it.... and expects banned to not start nor end with a @ (and if they do it really won't matter to the below))

`Where concat('@', banned,'@') like '%@Bob@%'`

Use find in set by converting the @ to a , and if the result is > 1 then it was found.

`find_in_set('Bob',replace(banned,','))>1`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the list is always composed of 2 or 3 names (as stated in your comment), the most straightforward way is to check for all 3 possible cases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people
WHERE list LIKE 'bob@%'    /* name in first position */
   OR list LIKE '%@bob@%'  /* name in second position */
   OR list LIKE '%@bob'    /* name in third, final position */
```

Comment: I like it, can use indexes; but 3 ors... ooof.  on performance but still may be better than selected answer... have to test.  it might actually be faster to do each search in it's own select and union the results!

Comment: Unfortunately indexes can't be used for the second two LIKEs given the wildcard '%... ' at the start of the string -- that being said, if performance proves a big issue, then restructuring this data scheme may be the best issue.

Comment: True %bob% can't use index; but the other 2 could. Still like it :P

Answer (score 1):

You should use concat for build a proper like condition  with vars and @

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE banned LIKE concat('%@%', '$Bob','%@%')
```

Comment: would bob be returned if banned contained bob@sam@smith or sam@smith@bob?  Really need to put the @ on the banned and search.

Comment: NO ... should be returnd only if  @bob@  as requested  by OP

Comment: But the example shows Roger@Bobjob@Billy... If we had to search for Roger it wouldn't return; and I think it should.  my point is the names at the first or last position don't have a @ starting and ending so they will never match the concat string.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal data structure, but leaving that aside for the moment:

If you can change the delimiter to a comma, mysql has a built-in function for that: [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Bob', list);
```

Otherwise, you can do a regular expression match.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE list REGEXP '(^|@)Bob($|@)';
```

Neither of these is necessarily very performant, so I wouldn't try it on large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best db architecture but you might use regular expressions for you purposes like so

`SELECT * FROM people WHERE banned RLIKE '(^|@)Bob($|@)'`